# Cost of common operations for C#?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, operators

In [Code Complete 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) (page 601 and 602) there is a table of "Cost of Common Operations".

The baseline operation integer assignment is given a value 1 and then the relative time for common operations is listed for Java and C++. For example:

```
                                  C++        Java
Integer assignment                1             1
Integer division                  5             1.5
Floating point square root       15             4
```

The question is has anyone got this data for C#? I know that these won't help me solve any problems specifically, I'm just curious.

Comment: (and it would be the same for all .NET languages)

Comment: Looks like premature optimization of premature optimization... These operations will be executed in assembly code but benchmark will run in actual runtime and IMHO it will test that benchmark is slow, not the machine instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from the source, **[Know what things cost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx)**.

IIRC Rico Mariani had relative measures as the ones you asked for [on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/default.aspx), I can't find it anymore, though (I know it's in one of thoe twohudnred "dev" bookmarks...)

Answer (score 12):

I implemented some of the tests from the book. Some raw data from my computer:

Test Run #1:

TestIntegerAssignment 00:00:00.6680000
  TestCallRoutineWithNoParameters 00:00:00.9780000
  TestCallRoutineWithOneParameter 00:00:00.6580000
  TestCallRoutineWithTwoParameters 00:00:00.9650000
  TestIntegerAddition  00:00:00.6410000
  TestIntegerSubtraction 00:00:00.9630000
  TestIntegerMultiplication 00:00:00.6490000
  TestIntegerDivision  00:00:00.9720000
  TestFloatingPointDivision 00:00:00.6500000
  TestFloatingPointSquareRoot 00:00:00.9790000
  TestFloatingPointSine 00:00:00.6410000
  TestFloatingPointLogarithm 00:00:41.1410000
  TestFloatingPointExp 00:00:34.6310000

Test Run #2:

TestIntegerAssignment 00:00:00.6750000
  TestCallRoutineWithNoParameters 00:00:00.9720000
  TestCallRoutineWithOneParameter 00:00:00.6490000
  TestCallRoutineWithTwoParameters 00:00:00.9750000
  TestIntegerAddition  00:00:00.6730000
  TestIntegerSubtraction 00:00:01.0300000
  TestIntegerMultiplication 00:00:00.7000000
  TestIntegerDivision  00:00:01.1120000
  TestFloatingPointDivision 00:00:00.6630000
  TestFloatingPointSquareRoot 00:00:00.9860000
  TestFloatingPointSine 00:00:00.6530000
  TestFloatingPointLogarithm 00:00:39.1150000
  TestFloatingPointExp 00:00:33.8730000

Test Run #3:

TestIntegerAssignment 00:00:00.6590000
  TestCallRoutineWithNoParameters 00:00:00.9700000
  TestCallRoutineWithOneParameter 00:00:00.6680000
  TestCallRoutineWithTwoParameters 00:00:00.9900000
  TestIntegerAddition  00:00:00.6720000
  TestIntegerSubtraction 00:00:00.9770000
  TestIntegerMultiplication 00:00:00.6580000
  TestIntegerDivision  00:00:00.9930000
  TestFloatingPointDivision 00:00:00.6740000
  TestFloatingPointSquareRoot 00:00:01.0120000
  TestFloatingPointSine 00:00:00.6700000
  TestFloatingPointLogarithm 00:00:39.1020000
  TestFloatingPointExp 00:00:35.3560000

(1 Billion Tests Per Benchmark, Compiled with Optimize, AMD Athlon X2 3.0ghz, using Jon Skeet's microbenchmarking framework available at http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/benchmark.html)

Source:

```
class TestBenchmark  
{  
[Benchmark]  
public static void TestIntegerAssignment()
{
int i = 1;
int j = 2;

    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++)
    {
        i = j;
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public static void TestCallRoutineWithNoParameters()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++)
    {
        TestStaticRoutine();
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public static void TestCallRoutineWithOneParameter()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++)
    {
        TestStaticRoutine2(5);
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public static void TestCallRoutineWithTwoParameters()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++)
    {
        TestStaticRoutine3(5,7);
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public static void TestIntegerAddition()
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    int k = 3;

    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++)
    {
        i = j + k;
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public static void TestIntegerSubtraction()
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 6;
    int k = 3;

    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++)
    {
        i = j - k;
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public static void TestIntegerMultiplication()
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    int k = 3;

    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++)
    {
        i = j * k;
    }
}


[Benchmark]
public static void TestIntegerDivision()
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 6;
    int k = 3;

    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++)
    {
        i = j/k;
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public static void TestFloatingPointDivision()
{
    float i = 1;
    float j = 6;
    float k = 3;

    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++)
    {
        i = j / k;
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public static void TestFloatingPointSquareRoot()
{
    double x = 1;
    float y = 6;

    for (int x2 = 0; x2 < 1000000000; x2++)
    {
        x = Math.Sqrt(6);
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public static void TestFloatingPointSine()
{
    double x = 1;
    float y = 6;

    for (int x2 = 0; x2 < 1000000000; x2++)
    {
        x = Math.Sin(y);
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public static void TestFloatingPointLogarithm()
{
    double x = 1;
    float y = 6;

    for (int x2 = 0; x2 < 1000000000; x2++)
    {
        x = Math.Log(y);
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public static void TestFloatingPointExp()
{
    double x = 1;
    float y = 6;

    for (int x2 = 0; x2 < 1000000000; x2++)
    {
        x = Math.Exp(6);
    }
}

private static void TestStaticRoutine() {

}

private static void TestStaticRoutine2(int i)
{

}

private static void TestStaticRoutine3(int i, int j)
{

}

private static class TestStaticClass
{

}
```

Comment: I'd do something with the result (like Console.WriteLine it) just to make absolutely sure that it doesn't get optimised away.  It probably won't, but ...

Comment: Don't you think that it's a bit strange every result is either ~0.33, ~0.66 or ~0.99? Especially when calls with 0,1,2 arguments get 0.9, 0.6, 0.9, I'd start getting suspicious about the testing method. Also private static functions can be inlined. That was a very bad test IMHO.

Comment: This benchmark test is bogus.  Each test has the overhead of doing 1000000000 additions as well because of the addition used in the loop.  In order to do this test correctly, you probably need to figure out how much time was spend doing the addition of 1000000000 numbers as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's a reasonable question, but nearly every performance problem I've seen, especially in Java and C# boiled down to:

- too many layers of abstraction, and
- reliance on event-based notification-style coding.

which have little or nothing to do with basic operations.

The problem with abstraction is it is fine until the workload gets heavy. Each layer usually exacts a small performance penalty, and these accumulate in a compounded fashion. At that point you start needing workarounds. (I think StringBuilder is an example of such a workaround.)

The problem with event-based notification-style coding (as opposed to simpler data structures kept consistent by a periodic process) is that what can seem like simple actions, such as setting a property to a value, can result in a ripple effect of actions throughout the data structure doing far more than one might expect.